# htacess rewrite rule return wrong value in query string

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule but it is not working as expected.

Rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ category.php?cat_alias=$1
```

In server side I get filename as value in request

```
Array
(
    [cat_alias] => category.php
)
```

Below is the example url for this rewrite rule
http://www.example.com/news

Expected result :

```
Array
    (
        [cat_alias] => news
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your rule doesn't have conditions and it is writing anything that is not `/` to `category.php`. After it rewrite `/news` rules are executed again in next loop and it performs another rewrite of `/category.php`.

You need to add rewrite condition to prevent existing files and directories to be rewritten and prevent looping.

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ category.php?cat_alias=$1 [L,QSA]
```